# Trying to pass a binary search tree as a parameter when calling the function

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to call a function in the console, but having trouble passing the right parameter to it. I keep getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined
```

But when I run it in Leetcode, it runs just fine.

Code:

```
        var levelOrderBottom = function(root) {
            if (root === null) { return []; }
            let result = [];
            let queue = [root];
            while(queue.length > 0) {
                let size = queue.length;
                let current = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    let head = queue.shift();
                    current.push(head.val);
                    if(head.left !== null) { queue.push(head.left); }
                    if(head.right !== null) { queue.push(head.right); }
                }
                result.unshift(current);
            }
            return result;
        };
        console.log("works", levelOrderBottom([3,9,20,null,null,15,7]));
```

Comment: so, and what is `head` ?

Comment: The function seems to expect a linked list.

Comment: Yes. You pass an array, but you should probably be passing something like `{ val: 9, left: { val: 3, left: null, right: null }, right: null }` or, more likely, an object from a node class.

Comment: @MOehm thank you! that helps